# Get second largest mark from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table `student` with the fields id, name and mark.
I need to get the student name(s) having second largest mark.

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM stud ORDER BY mark DESC LIMIT 2,1
```

but that returns only one student name having second second largest mark.

I need to list all student names if many of them having second largest mark.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  name, mark
FROM
  stud 
WHERE
  mark = (SELECT MAX(mark) FROM stud WHERE mark < (SELECT MAX(mark) FROM stud))
ORDER BY
  name
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also similar to the above.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, mark
FROM stud WHERE mark = (SELECT mark FROM stud ORDER BY mark DESC LIMIT 1, 1)
ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

We will get the second largest mark of the stud table by using the bellow query.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM
  stud as a 
WHERE
  2= (SELECT COUNT(b.id) FROM stud as B WHERE a.mark <=b.mark)
```